# Show that both set A and set B are Turing reducible to some mixture of A and B

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, oracle-machines

Consider an operator $+$ defined on $P(N)$ as follows: $A + B = \{2x\mid x \in A\}\cup \{2x + 1\mid x \in B\}$.

Show that both $A$ and $B$ are Turing-reducible to $A+B$
I am kind of confused about this notion of turing reducibility thing.
Does it mean that There is a turing machine which converts an input from $A$ to an element of $B$
on the tape. There is a term called `oracle` that also pops up. So if we have an oracle for $B$ 
does it mean that there is a decider for $B$? What's an intuitive workable definition of oracle?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Turing reducible, is that there exists a [Turing reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) - an algorithm for $A$ (or $B$) that uses an oracle to $A+B$.

To understand this, you must first understand [oracle machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine). Those machines, are like turing machines, but can ask an "oracle" whether any $x$ is in $A$ or not, and would get an answer in $O(1)$, regardless of what $A$ is (doesn't even matter if it is not decidable!)

So, a turing reduction between $A$ and $A+B$ basically means that if you know for any $x$ whether its in $A+B$ or not, then you can decide whether a given $x$ is in $A$. Formally, this statement can be written as $A^{(A+B)}\in R$.

So basically the question asks you to show that both $A^{(A+B)},B^{(A+B)}\in R$

Comment: So when asked to show that A is turing reducible to A+B. Does that amount to that if given y we could determine if it is in A+B. by using the oracle for A ? So if y/2 is in A then y is in A+B certainly. But in case y is of the form 2x+1 where x is in B. In that case we don't have an oracle for B to determine this. I am kind of confused here how to complete the argument

Comment: If I understand correctly there is no need to run a turing machine with states and symbols here. And when you talk about oracle for A it just means there is a decider for A

Comment: @JohnL. You are right, my bad! But the idea stays the same

Comment: @nirshahar  "$A^{(A+B)}\in R$" should have been "$A\in\text{R}^{(A+B)}$. "if you can decide" should be better than "if you know ...".